# Can I display lists (<ol>, <ul>) as inline items?

Tags: html, list, html-lists, inline

I know they are block elements, but I'm sure there is a way, maybe with CSS? I tried to use the span tag but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong? I would like to put the second element next to the first one on the website. Not under it, but next.

```
  <span>
        <section>
        <h3>Favourite quotes</h3>
         <ul>
          <li>
              “Pizza is good" ―Me
          </li>     
         </ul>
        </section>
  </span>

  <span>
        <section>
        <h3>Favourite series</h3>
         <ul>
          <li> X </li>
          <li> Y </li>
          <li> Z </li> 
         </ul>
        </section>
  </span>
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate what specifically didn't work, and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the two "span" "inline-block" display and that's it!

```css
.first,.second{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <span class="first">
        <section>
        <h3>Favourite quotes</h3>
         <ul>
          <li>
              “Pizza is good" ―Me
          </li>     
         </ul>
        </section>
  </span>

  <span class="second">
        <section>
        <h3>Favourite series</h3>
         <ul>
          <li> X </li>
          <li> Y </li>
          <li> Z </li> 
         </ul>
        </section>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `span` this way is wrong because `span` is [`inline` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) and you can't wrap `section` like this and any other `block`'s. You can use `<table>` or flexbox for this case.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container section {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h3>Favourite quotes</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>“Pizza is good" ―Me</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Favourite series</h3>
    <ul>
      <li> X </li>
      <li> Y </li>
      <li> Z </li> 
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```